# Inserting the Object into map or array or victor as a constructor of the object

Tags: c++, constructor, containers

hello I am beginner in cpp, is there away that I can save an object automaticaly after being created to a map or any kind of containers?  in this simple example i can say that the problem is that the object is not created yet so how can I refer to an uncreated object in the constructor.?

```
class A {
public: 
    A(parameter){
        map.emplace(key,object);//what should I write in the second field ?
    }
};
```

Comment: Just add a static factory method `A::create(parameter)`. Create the object, add it to the map and then return it (beware o returning a copy).

Comment: `std::map::emplace` calls your constructor for you, so you should be doing something like `map.emplace (key, 42)` (assuming that `parameter` is an `int`).

Comment: good tip I will try it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment, you can use a static method:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>


struct A {
    int x;
    A(int x) : x(x) {}
    static auto create_in_map(int key,int x, std::map<int,A>& m) {
        return m.emplace(key,x).first;
    }
};
int main() {
    std::map<int,A> map;
    auto it = A::create_in_map(1,2,map);
    std::cout << "key: " << it->first << " value: " << it->second.x;
}
```

Note that standard containers own their elements, ie you do not want to first create an `A` and then place it in the map, because you would end up with two instances: The one you created and the copy inside the map. [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) takes the key and parameters for `A`s constructor and creates the instance directly in the map. It returns a `std::pair<iterator,bool>`, the iterator points to the inserted element and the `bool` indicates whether the element actually has been inserted (it isn't when the key is already present). In the code I ignored the `bool` and only returned the iterator. The iterators `->first` is the key and its `->second` is the `A` the was created in the method.

Last but not least, the above code is only for illustration. There is no need for that static method. You should simply write `map.emplace(1,2)` in `main`.

Comment: yes that seems actually the right way to do it thank you very much